# Typescript throws error when returning array of data in redux createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

So I am using the following code to fetch list of users,

```
export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchById",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue, fulfillWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users`)
      const j = (await response.json()) as MyData[]
      return fulfillWithValue(j)
    } catch (e) {
      return rejectWithValue(e.response)
    }
  }
)
```

Typescript gives following error,

```
Argument of type '(_: void, { rejectWithValue, fulfillWithValue }: GetThunkAPI<{}>) => Promise<RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> | FulfillWithMeta<MyData[], unknown>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<MyData[], void, {}>'.
  Type 'Promise<RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> | FulfillWithMeta<MyData[], unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreatorReturnValue<MyData[], {}>'.
    Type 'Promise<RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> | FulfillWithMeta<MyData[], unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> | MyData[]>'.
      Type 'RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> | FulfillWithMeta<MyData[], unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> | MyData[]'.
        Type 'FulfillWithMeta<MyData[], unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown> | MyData[]'.
          Type 'FulfillWithMeta<MyData[], unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown>'.
            Types have separate declarations of a private property '_type'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: It is telling you that your function passed in does not have the correct signature that the function expects (`AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<MyData[], void, {}>`).

Comment: Sorry but I am returning `MyData[]` though? @crashmstr

Comment: The function you pass to `createAsyncThunk` need to have the right parameters *and* the right return type. The error is telling you it is not what is expected.

Comment: Do you mean I should do `export const fetchUserById: AsyncThunk<MyData[], any, {}>`? And if so it doesn't seem to work either. @crashmstr

Comment: Also why should I go through this with array though? It works perfectly fine if data is an object so something like `const j = (await response.json()) as MyData` works.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? [createAsyncThunk - payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) shows that your `thunkAPI` is not right and missing properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a type for `fulfillWithValue` property of `ThunkApiConfig` generic parameter.

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

interface MyData {}

export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk<MyData[], void, { fulfilledMeta: any }>(
  'users/fetchById',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue, fulfillWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users`);
      const j = await response.json();
      return fulfillWithValue(j, null);
    } catch (e) {
      return rejectWithValue(e.response);
    }
  },
);
```

package version: `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0"`

[Reference source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/8565fc25803beedc1032d67473c6b448da588405/packages/toolkit/src/tests/createAsyncThunk.typetest.ts#L440)

Comment: when do we need to use `fulfillWithValue`, can't we return directly?